# SHLoadImageFile is returning error code 6

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I am trying to load an image using SHLoadImageFile,but its returning invalid handle.
I am puzzled where the fault is.Because the path given to SHLoadImageFile is absolutely fine.

Comment: Are you sure the file format of the image is supported? What version of windows are you running and what kind of image are you trying to load?

Comment: What path you have given? Probably you have used '\' incorrectly.

Comment: @ user786653 : Yeah the file format of the image is jpg and yes it is supported by this api(SHLoadImage).

Answer (score 0):

The question title currently is "SHLoadImage is returning error code 6". But `SHLoadImage` return is a handle, not an error code. So perhaps this *means* that you have called `GetLastError`?

If so, then error code 6 is defined in `<winerror.h>` as

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE
//
// MessageText:
//
// The handle is invalid.
//
#define ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE             6L
```

The documentation does not however say anything about `SHLoadImage` setting the last error code, so perhaps this is something from earlier in the execution. Try using `SetLastError` to set the last error code to 0 before calling `SHLoadImage`.

For more specific advice you need to include more specific information, like showing the code with the "absolutely fine" path. If it really is, perhaps the file doesn't exist. Or is not a valid image.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Oh yeah.... i missed that..since ShLoadImage was returning invalid handle,I tried to check the error code using GetLastError.

Comment: @ Steinbach :To be more specific,I am querying the registry path where the images are stored in the device and then i am giving that path(including the name of the image) as the filename argument for SHLoadImage. I am sure about the correctness of path because I have rechecked the path's existance in the device side manually